# Setting up ssl for localhost wo a domain

Tags: openssl

I need to set up a self cert ssl for my localhost on ubuntu 18. I am trying to follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04. In it, when creating the cert, these are the magic questions:
Output

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:New York
Locality Name (eg, city) []:New York City
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Bouncy 
Castles, Inc.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Ministry of Water Slides
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:server_IP_address
Email Address []:admin@your_domain.com
```

What do I do about the common name? There is no public domain in my case. I am using localhost, 127.0.0.1 . The reason I even need ssl is that my code uses oauth2 which requires ssl. Do I somehow need to make my local host publicly accessible?

Comment: If you're only running your app on localhost, you could simply use `localhost` as the common name, or the host name. It doesn't particularly matter, since your browser isn't going to trust the certificate anyway.